# Why does Yisro tell Moshe that he came with Moshe's wife "and her sons" rather than "your sons"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, children-parenting, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-yisro, yisro--the-man

At Exodus 18:6, Moshe's father-in-law, Yisro, tells Moshe that he had come with Moshe's wife and "her sons." Why didn't he say to Moshe that she had come with "your sons"?

Comment: על דרך צחות: According to the opinions that Yisro came after Matan Torah, they actually weren't Moshe's sons anymore, because גר שנתגייר כקטן שנולד דמי.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [Alshich](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35888&st=&pgnum=275) explains that Yisro was worried: Perhaps Moshe would not be interested in a Midyanite woman and would rather marry a Jewess. He therefore emphasized that he brought "*her* two sons" with him (and not "*his* two sons"), since a man comes to like his wife because of the children she bears him, and this would persuade Moshe to remarry Tziporah. (See also [Maskil Ledovid on Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19148&st=&pgnum=142&hilite=) for a very similar explanation)
- [Rabbeynu Bechaya](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14069&st=&pgnum=227&hilite=) explains that the way of the Pesukim is to link sons to their mother and daughters to the father. (see [Rashi 46:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8241/showrashi/true) "The males are attributed to Leah and the females to Jacob").

Comment: Good answer -- better than I could find, or the half-dozen rabbis I asked this weekend.  But is there any possibility that Yisro was being critical of Moshe; suggesting that while Moshe was in Egypt, Tzipora was raising his children?

Comment: @BruceJames Sounds like an interesting idea, but I would be hesitant to accept that for a couple reasons - a) Moshe originally planned to bring his wife and children with him to Egypt and was later persuaded not to by Aahron for their own safety (see Rashi to 18:2). Surely Yisro would understand that Moshe had his children's best interests in mind. b) Yisro seems worried that Moshe will not come out and meet him (see Rashi to 18:6) and is trying to convince him to come. It will be ill-timed at that point for him to be telling him off.

Comment: Regarding your point b): It is that Rashi that led me to ask the question. If Yisro was worried that Moshe would not come out to see him, that might be more of a reason to say that he brought "your children" rather than "her children." The opinion of the Alshich might make sense it that was the mind-set of that generation. I would think in our era the father might interpret Yisro's statement as if to say, "your sons are no longer yours." Interestingly, I think this is the last we hear about Moshe's sons.

Comment: @BruceJames Rashi there does seem to strengthen the question, but see the Maskil Ledovid I quoted who writes that this is actually the *basis* for Rashi's remark.